# WebComponents - what's the advantage of using CSS Custom Properties in the Component Public Interface?

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, css-variables

A `WebComponent` may include **CSS Custom Properties** in its encapsulated styles.

This gives consumers of the component *a way to customise that component's styles*:

- See: [Creating style hooks using CSS custom properties | Google Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#stylehooks)

Declaring

```
--fancy-tabs-bg: red
```

in the *main styles* means that when the `shadow-root` styles include

```
background-color: var(--fancy-tabs-bg, #9E9E9E)
```

the `background-color` will be `red` (or whatever value `--fancy-tabs-bg` is set to).

---

**But...** I note in the same article it explicitly states:

> One gotcha with `:host` is that rules in the parent page have higher
> specificity than `:host` rules defined in the element. That is,
> outside styles win. This allows users to override your top-level
> styling from the outside.

and again, later:

> **Outside styles always win over styles defined in shadow DOM.** For example, if the user writes the selector `fancy-tabs { width: 500px; }`, it will trump the component's rule: `:host { width: 650px;}`

So... instead of declaring a value for `--fancy-tabs-bg` we could just... set a value for `background-color` (?)

Really? Let's find out.

Here's a `WebComponent` (largely copied from the article referenced above) where the first two instances of the component are styled using a **CSS Custom Property** (ie. `--fancy-tabs-bg`) and the third instance is styled directly, using the relevant **CSS Property** (ie. `background-color`).

```js
class FancyTabs extends HTMLElement {
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.root = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
  }

  connectedCallback() {
  
    this.root.innerHTML = `
    
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 6px;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
      
      :host([background]) {
        background-color: var(--fancy-tabs-bg, #9E9E9E);
      }
    </style>
    
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('fancy-tabs', FancyTabs);
```

```css
fancy-tabs {
  float: left;
}

fancy-tabs:nth-of-type(1) {
  --fancy-tabs-bg: red;
}

fancy-tabs:nth-of-type(2) {
  --fancy-tabs-bg: orange;
}

fancy-tabs:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<fancy-tabs background>...</fancy-tabs>
<fancy-tabs background>...</fancy-tabs>
<fancy-tabs background>...</fancy-tabs>
```

There's no difference, is there?

So why use **CSS Custom Properties** at all? Why highlight in the public interface that a particular CSS property is available for user-customisation? Surely **all** CSS properties are available for user-customisation, aren't they?

What am I missing?

Comment: Ohhh... is it that _both_ approaches (ie. the `custom-property` approach and the `property` approach) are entirely valid, but `custom-property-values` are a more useful tool when the same value needs to be declared multiple times for multiple CSS properties in the `Shadow DOM`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't notice any difference when dealing with the host element but you can clearly see the use of CSS variables when having more elements inside:

Example where CSS variables is useful to update the styling of nested elements. I doubt you can find a better way without CSS variables.

```js
class FancyTabs extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' });
    const css = `
     :host {
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 6px;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
      
     :host([background]) {
        background-color: var(--fancy-tabs-bg, #9E9E9E);
      }
      div {
        padding: var(--p,0px);
        border:var(--b,0px) solid;
      }`
    this.styles = document.createElement('style');
    this.styles.innerHTML = css;
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    this.shadow.appendChild(this.styles);
    this.shadow.appendChild(div);
  }
}

customElements.define('fancy-tabs', FancyTabs);
```

```css
fancy-tabs {
  float: left;
}

fancy-tabs:nth-of-type(1) {
  --fancy-tabs-bg: red;
  --p:20px;
  --b:5px;
}

fancy-tabs:nth-of-type(2) {
  --fancy-tabs-bg: orange;
  --p:10px;
  --b:3px;
}
fancy-tabs:nth-of-type(3) {
  --fancy-tabs-bg: orange;
  padding:20px; /* will get applied to host*/
  border-width:5px; /* will do nothing */
}
```

```html
<fancy-tabs background>text  here</fancy-tabs>
<fancy-tabs background>text  here</fancy-tabs>
<fancy-tabs background>text  here</fancy-tabs>
```

Comment: Great work, thank you, @TemaniAfif - a very clear explanation showing the advantages of using _CSS Custom Properties_ with **nested elements** inside the `Shadow DOM`.